# Reusing a QProcess object (Qt 4.8)

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

Given the following code:

```
QProcess myProcess;

myProcess.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);

myProcess.start(/* whatever */);
myProcess.closeWriteChannel();

// More code, like waitForStarted() and other specifics.

myProcess.start(/* whatever */); // Line (1)
```

After line (1), is the standard input channel of the new process open or closed? I mean, does QProcess remember your choices for each new thrown process or they must be set each time? In such case, which QProcess properties reset and which don't?

Comment: starting is asynchronuos, if you want to ensure for starting to be completed (or failed), call waitForStarted(). I'd consider to create a new QProcess object for each process run.

Comment: Perhaps I should mention that in the question, but your considerations are omitted in my code under the "// More code" comment.

Comment: Ok, I've already mentioned that. You are the second person who warns me about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
myProcess.start(/* whatever */); // Line (1)
```

You should get "QProcess::start: Process is already running" warning on line (1)....

Comment: Suppose in "// more code" there's a `waitForFinished()` call.

Comment: @Peregring-lk : As per my knowledge QProcess must be set each time...even you can cross check `qDebug()<<myProcess.isOpen();` to make sure...